# electric circuit with circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

i am using "circuitikz", but i can´t make this electric circuit! 
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw [-o](0.25,4)--(0,4)node[left]{$V_i(t)$};
\draw (0.25,4)to[R,l=$R_1$, a={{3,456}{$\Omega$}},-*](4,4)to[C,-*,l2^=$C_1$ 
 and {1}{$\mu F$}](4,0)node[ground](GND){};
\draw [-o](4,0)--(0,0)node[left]{$-$};
\draw [-o](4,4)--(6,4)node[right]{$V_o(t)$};
\draw [-o](4,0)--(6,0)node[right]{$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Filtro Pasabajo}
\end{figure}
```

i did this!
[image]

Help me, please! Thanks..

Comment: Hi and welcome! What version of circuitikz did you use to create this figure?

Comment: I dont know. I just include the \usepackage {circuitikz} on latex

Comment: It would be nice if your share your work in progress with us (i.e. a compileable minimal working example of your progress) and tell us about your knowledge level regarding tikz and circuitikz.

Comment: I just edited the post with the code and image I made!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,2)   to[R=$R$,o-*]  (3,2)  
                to[short, -o]  (5,2)
        (3,2)   to[C=$C$, -*]  (3,0)
                node[ground,below]  {}
        (0,0)   node[ground,below]  {}
        (5,0)   node[ground,below]  {}
        (0,0)   to[open, v^=$v_i(t)$, o-] (0,2)
        (5,0)   to[open, v_=$v_o(t)$, o-] (5,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
The second image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,2)   to[R=$R$,o-*]  (3,2)  
                to[short, -o]  (5,2)
        (3,2)   to[C=$C$, -*]  (3,0)
        (0,0)   to[short,o-o]  (5,0)
        (3,0)   node[ground,below]  {}
        (0,2)   node[left] {$V_i(t)$}
        (0,0)   node[left] {$-$}
        (5,2)   node[right] {$V_o(t)$}
        (5,0)   node[right] {$-$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @MatiasTevez, you are velcome. BTW, you can up-vote answer (by click on up-pen at left top side of answer) ar even accept it (by clicking on check mark)  :-)

Comment: @Rmano, ojej (huh in eng.), I miss coordinate. I will correct this asap.