# Who can help me to write a code to draw my circuit?

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

This is the circuit, I have to insert it into a document written with LaTex but i can't write a good code to draw the circuit with all details i need. Suggestion? Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Plz. show us what you tried and where you are stuck. E.g. have you searched for "latex circuit"? You most probably will directly find [circuitikz manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf)

Comment: There are many example of circuits at this site.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538454/electric-circuit-with-circuitikz as one of the simpler cases.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are novice here ...

For starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, cute inductors]{circuitikz} % <---
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height=0.5,
          bipoles/capacitor/width=0.1,
          bipoles/length=1cm
          }

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)                           coordinate (aux0)
                to[sV]      ++ (0,1.5)
                to[R=$R_G$] ++ (0,1.5)  coordinate (aux1)
                to[R=$R$]   ++ (2,0)    coordinate (aux2)
        (aux2)  to[R=$R_L$] ++ (0,-1.2)
                to[L=$V_o$] ++ (0,-1.2)
                to[C=$C$]   ++ (0,-0.6)
                to[short,*-*]  (aux0)
        (aux1)  to[short,*-o] ++ (-1.5,0)
                to[open, v=$v_{\mathrm{in}}$, voltage=straight]     ++ (0,-3)
                to[short,o-*]    (aux0)
        (aux2)  to[short,*-o] ++ (1.5,0)
                to[open, v^=$v_{\mathrm{out}}$, voltage=straight]   ++ (0,-3)
                to[short,o-*]  (aux2 |- aux0)
                ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I strongly recommend to read package manual and see different examples of `circuitikz` scheme here on site.